# fsck crashes when booting from USB

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot, sd-card, boot-issues

I have set up my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B to boot from a USB flash drive like in [this article](https://samhobbs.co.uk/2013/10/speed-up-your-pi-by-booting-to-a-usb-flash-drive). Basically, I have burned the Raspbian image to a USB drive, then copied the boot partition to my SD card, and edited `cmdline.txt` in the following way:

Modified `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` to `root=/dev/sda2`

Whenever I try and boot my Raspberry, I get the following message:

```
Checking file system...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
open: No such file or directory
dosfsck 3.0.13, 30 Jun 2012, FAT32, LFM
fsck died with exit status 6
fsck died with exit code 6
[FAIL] File system check failed. 
[warn] A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and resume system boot
```

When I try fsck in the maintenance shell, I get the following error:

```
No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

When I control-d uit of the shell, the system boots normally.

Why does this error take place and what can I do about it?

Comment: @hoedjes didz you try to switch the usb to another slotz?

Comment: Is the old root device /dev/mmcblk0p2 still mentioned in /etc/fstab ?

Comment: How did you copy the boot partition, exactly?

Comment: @Frepa Yup. Should I comment out that line since /dev/sda is already mounted?

Comment: @Maarten I'd say just change the line to point to the new root partition, replace  /dev/mmcblk0p2 by /dev/sda2 (I assume sda2 is your new root partition).